# Android + gradle: injecting a task into build

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a custom script which runs on the source (.java) and AndroidManifest.xml.
I'd like to execute this script as part of the gradle build process at the start of the assembleRelease task (maybe just after app:preBuild).

Any idea of how I can go about doing this?

I know I can do something like this to exec the script:

```
task DoStuff(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'path/to/script'
    commandLine 'python3', 'do_stuff.py'
}
```

But I'm not sure where to put that, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom action to `assembleRelease` with `doFirst` method:

```
assembleRelease.doFirst {
   //invoke python script but there's no access to `workingDir` or `commandLine` 
   //because it's an action not a task
}
```

or define dependency:

```
assembleRelease.dependsOn DoStuff
assembleRelease.mustRunAfter DoStuff //this might be redundant
```

Comment: `assembleRelease.dependsOn` qorked perfectly thanks! also used `assembleRelease.finalizedBy` to run stuff after task

Comment: What if I'm ussing flavors?

Comment: these lines should be added inside of `afterEvaluate` like
`afterEvaluate {
bundleReleaseAar.finalizedBy DoStuff
}`